# Angular: 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl': registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange, _applyFormState

Tags: angular, angular8

I am using a snippet to interate all form controls in a formGroup. The snippet worked well at the start but all of a sudden angular started complaining

```
 Object.keys(this.frmCadastroImobiliaria.controls).forEach(key => {

  const fc: FormControl = this.frmCadastroImobiliaria.get(key); //here I got an error

  if(fc.touched === true) {
    fcs.push(fc);
  }

});
```

this.frmCadastroImobiliaria is my formGroup.

The error says:

```
 Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl': registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange, _applyFormState
```

Comment: I changed fc to AbstractControl and apparently worked.

Comment: but you can't use some methods which have FormControl, your TS will give errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Template error Type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to type 'FormControl'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834802/template-error-type-abstractcontrol-is-not-assignable-to-type-formcontrol)

Comment: this works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834802/template-error-type-abstractcontrol-is-not-assignable-to-type-formcontrol/72517767#72517767

Answer (score 7):

You can use typescript assertion(`as`).

```
const fc: FormControl = this.frmCadastroImobiliaria.get(key) as FormControl;
```

Comment: cool, thanks! But why? I thought the whole point of typing and interfaces was that compatible types would share the same interface.

Comment: Look. the `get` function of the `FormGroup`, `FormControl` and `FormArray` returns the `AbstractControl` which doesn't same as `FormControl`. you need to use assertion and tell the compiler that, the returned type is the `FormControl` instead of `AbstractControl`.