# Template error Type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to type 'FormControl'

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Why am I getting this error?

The following code works in another application

```
          <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" min="0"
            [formControl]='invoiceForm.get("quantity")'>
```

in this new application it works too but still complaining in the terminal

```
  Type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to type 'FormControl'.
```

Answer (score 41):

```html
<input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control" [formControl]="$any(myForm).controls['confirmpassword']"/>
```

Use the [$any](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#disabling-type-checking-using-any) function to disable type checking. I resolved my error by using this.

Comment: See @Avetik comment bellow for a much cleaner solution with a pipe. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72517767/3669310

Answer (score 34):

If someone else still have this issue, I share my solution, which is almost the same as [Bellash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/733889/bellash) was described but with better perfomance.
For this example:

```
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" min="0"
        [formControl]='invoiceForm.get("quantity")' | formControl>
```

we just need to create and use pipe which will return for us value with correct type

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'formControl',
})
export class FormControlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: AbstractControl): FormControl<typeof value['value']> {
        return value as FormControl<typeof value['value']>;
    }
}
```

In this way you will have better perfomance since pipe transform function will be called only when provided form will be changed.

Generally it is bad practice to use functions in templates, because this functions will be called on each lifecycle change, and will have big perfomance issues on bigger projects. The best way is to use pipes, which generally was developed exactly for such purposes, to transform some values on rendering only when this will be changed.
Hope this will help someone)

Comment: Exactly. I use the same exact pipe in the project. Didn't remember to update this answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: Better solution than others. But I had to remove generics <typeof value['value']> in Angular 13.

Comment: You mention it's bad practice to use functions in templates, but still call a function in your template: `invoiceForm.get("quantity")`. If the function is inexpensive like both of these are (map get and type casting), then it won't have the performance issues you mention. ...but if you truly want to get rid of the function calls, you could either add the `get` to your pipe, eg `invoiceForm | formControl: 'quantity'`, or you could just use Angular's built-in `formControlName` instead of `formControl`

Comment: You can't do this with TS ==> TS2315: Type 'FormControl' is not generic.

Comment: @JulienFEGER Before Angular 14, FormControl wasn't generic. Angular 14+ has replaced it with a generic type. [@DanCrosby has an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72931742/1082789) that is basically the same thing for Angular 13 and earlier.

Comment: I would recommend adding some type checking within the transform method. `AbstractControl` could possibly be a `FormControl`, `FormGroup`, or `FormArray`. If it's not actually a FormControl, casting it to one can cause hard to diagnose errors down the line. It would be better to throw an exception within `transform()` if you get a type different than expected, so the problem is immediately obvious.

Answer (score 13):

This issue might come from `tsconfig.json` if you're using Angular 9 or above

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    ...
    "strictTemplates": true <-- causing "Type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to type 'FormControl'"
  }
```

**First Option**

by setting `"strictTemplates": false` might temporary "solve" the problem

**Second Option**

by convert the `AbstractControl` to `FormControl` through template, so your `.ts` file should have

```
convertToFormControl(absCtrl: AbstractControl | null): FormControl {
    const ctrl = absCtrl as FormControl;
    return ctrl;
  }
```

and your `html`

```
<input
    type="text"
    [formControl]="convertToFormControl(invoiceForm.get("quantity"))"
  />
```

Comment: Do you mean `convertToFormControl(invoiceForm.get("quantity"))` ?

Comment: To me, this solution looks cleaner but having one drawback, template will keep calling this method continuously on each change detection cycle.

Answer (score 9):

From this [official documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlDirective) and according to the [FormControl definition](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl), we can see that FormControl inherits from AbstractControl. And since `FormGroup.controls` and `FormGroup.get("key")` both return an `AbstractControl`, I had to create a function to cast from Parent to Child class.

```
toControl(absCtrl: AbstractControl): FormControl {
    const ctrl = absCtrl as FormControl;
    // if(!ctrl) throw;
    return ctrl;
}
```

and the template

```
 <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" min="0"
        [formControl]='toControl(invoiceForm.get("quantity"))'>
```

PS: I could not use `FormControlName` because I have many form groups and sub groups/arrays. That's I had to use the banana in box directive, because it's value is strongly typed

**EDITs 2022**: Also consider @Avetik answer bellow to convert this function into a pipe for better performance

Comment: `get()` can also return `null`

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Avetik and Imo for most of the info I am listing.   The following steps work in Angular 13+:

Create a file form-control.pipe.ts in your base project folder:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractControl, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Pipe({
    name: 'formControl',
})
export class FormControlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: AbstractControl): FormControl {
        return value as FormControl;
    }
}
```

In the declarations section of @NgModule for your project, add FormControlPipe to the list and import it.

Anywhere you are getting this lint warning, add **| FormControl** (include the pipe symbol)

```
[formControl]="form.get('wordRuleForm').get('sound') | formControl"
```

Problem solved!

I had a similar control with formGroup, so I created a similar filter based on formGroup, and it is used like this:

```
[commonForm]="form.get('commonForm') | formGroup"
```

Comment: I would recommend adding some type checking within the transform method. `AbstractControl` could possibly be a `FormControl`, `FormGroup`, or `FormArray`. If it's not actually a FormControl, casting it to one can cause hard to diagnose errors down the line. It would be better to throw an exception within `transform()` if you get a type different than expected, so the problem is immediately obvious.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get around this issue by giving the template direct access to the `FormControl` as well as adding it to the form in `initForm()`.

.ts

```
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
quantity: FormControl = new FormControl(Quantity.MIN, [
  Validators.min(Quantity.MIN),
  Validators.max(Quantity.MAX),
]);

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.initForm();
}

initForm(): void {
  this.form.addControl('quantity', this.quantity);
}
```

.html  (In my case I am passing the `FormControl` quantity to a custom component that takes a `FormControl` `Input()` named "control".)

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <app-select-quantity [control]="quantity"></app-select-quantity>
  <div>
    <button
      mat-flat-button
      type="submit"
      color="primary"
      [disabled]="!form.valid"
    >
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This feels like the cleanest solution. Building the formGroup in the controller and using [formGroup] and formControlName directive to bind things together: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#grouping-form-controls

Answer (score 1):

```html
<input type="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" [formControl]="$any(cardForm).controls.name" />
```

Here `$any` function would disable type checking.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't really keen on using a workaround (which all the answers seemed to be), and happened to come across the strategy used in an [Angular University](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-validators/) example.

You can easily expose your form controls to your forms by exposing `get` properties to the `formControlName` on the template:

```
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" min="0"
formControlName='quantity'> <!-- formControlName instead of [formControl] -->
```

and in the component:

```
// The get property should match the formControlName above.
get quantity() {
  return this.form.controls["quantity"];
}
```

Comment: This is clean and perfect. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" min="0"
            [formControl]='invoiceForm.controls.quantity'>
```

or my personal favorite way of handlingforms

```
<div [formGroup]="inviceForm"> <!-- any tag that wraps all of your controls -->

      <!-- some input before (anything)-->
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" min="0"
                formControlName='quantity'>
           <!-- some inputs after (anything)-->
</div>
```

Comment: This will result into another error `controls does not exist on FormGroup`.  changing `invoiceForm` type to `any` will resolve the issue but I don't want to use any instead of FormGroup

Comment: Api says it does.

Comment: invoiceForm  was `any` but When  invoiceForm  is a `FormGroup` I still get `Type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to type 'FormControl'`.

Comment: Use approach with the formgroup and formcontrolname and you will be fine

Comment: from @angular/forms 

`export declare class FormGroup extends AbstractControl {
    controls: {
        [key: string]: AbstractControl;
    };`

Comment: Do you still have any problems? This part of API would need some improvements but apart of that, besides forcefully casting type of controls or return of get, you wont do anything about it.

Answer (score -1):

If there are different versions or no 'type' conversion matches you can use 'any' as a temporary solution. For e.g

From :

```
event: FormControl
```

To :

```
event: any
```