# 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm new to angular, and I'm learning reactive forms.

There's this one issue that I'm not able to solve. Here, I'm trying to create a reusable input component for my form. But, there's this `Abstractform control error` that I'm not able to resolve.

NOTE: I don't wanna use `"strictTemplates": false`.

Can someone help me understand what's exactly going on here and how can I resolve this error?

Here's the list of files to reproduce the error -

**reactive-form.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reactive-form',
  templateUrl: './reactive-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reactive-form.component.css'],
})
export class ReactiveFormComponent {
  cardForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
  })
}
```

**reactive-form.component.html** (Getting error here)

```
<form [formGroup]="cardForm"></form>

<!--Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl': registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange, _applyFormState  -->
<app-input [control]="cardForm.controls.name"></app-input>
```

**input.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.css'],
})
export class InputComponent {
  @Input() control: FormControl = new FormControl()
}
```

**input.component.html**

```
<input [formControl]="control" />
<ng-container *ngIf="control.dirty && control.touched && control.errors">
  <div *ngIf="control.errors.required">Value is required</div>
  <div *ngIf="control.errors.minlength">
    Value should be longer Required min value is
    {{ control.errors.minlength.requiredLength }}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

*NOTE:* I've already analyzed a couple of similar threads but those are hard for me to understand. Will appreciate it if someone can take this example and explain what's wrong here.

Comment: FYI, `angularjs`, `javascript` tags are not relevant to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Template error Type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to type 'FormControl'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834802/template-error-type-abstractcontrol-is-not-assignable-to-type-formcontrol)

Comment: This worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834802/template-error-type-abstractcontrol-is-not-assignable-to-type-formcontrol/72517767#72517767

Answer (score 4):

You get this error because Angular doesn't know that you are passing `FormControl`. Instead, Angular treats it as `AbstractControl`.

> Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl': registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange, _applyFormState

---

### Solution

Add `cardFormNameControl` getter to specify that you are passing `FormControl` to `InputComponent`.

> reactive.component.html

```
export class ReactiveFormComponent {
  ...

  get cardFormNameControl(): FormControl {
    return this.cardForm.get('name') as FormControl;
  }
}
```

```
<app-input [control]="cardFormNameControl"></app-input>
```

[Sample solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-atmke2?file=src/app/reactive-form/reactive-form.component.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more question -  Is there a way to make this getter more generic?  Like here, inside the getter, you're hardcoding the `name`. So, for each other input -  I may need to create a getter function. Is there an elegant way to solve this?

Comment: I think for this case you should pass the `FormGroup`? Not sure you want to pass every control or specific control?

Comment: I started learning angular a week ago. Thanks for the help. Will try your suggestion : )

Comment: We create a new type like `export type LoginFormControls = Record<keyof LoginForm, FormControl>;` where the `LoginForm` is an interface with the value types. After that we create a getter for the controls like `get controls() {return this.form.controls as LoginFormControls}` With this TypeScript knows the types and the properties of the controls.

Other solution can be using $any in your template `<app-input [control]="$any(cardForm.controls.name)"></app-input>` but it's a source of bugs. Use TypeScript and don't disable it.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, you may refer [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6mzvxf). What I did is adding `castFormControl` method to cast `AbstractControl` to `FormControl` and with `*ngFor (keyvalue pair)` to iterate each form control.

Comment: out of curiosity, if you place an HTML control in the form `<input ... formControlName="name" ... >` and pass `cardForm.controls['name']` would that work? I wonder, thus I stackoverflow :)

Comment: Hi @Ayyash, the changes you mentioned is as [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-juxsvx)? If yes, it will be the same issue as Post Owner asked: "AbstractControl ..."

Answer (score 1):

You can get another aproach that is use a getter in your compoment

```
control:FormControl=new FormControl();
@Input('control') set _(value)
{
  this.control=value as FormControl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input component must be like this:
ts file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input', 
  templateUrl: './input.component.css.html', 
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.css.css'], 
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,  
  providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR] })
export class InputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor,OnChanges{   
InputValue: any;  
@Input() control: FormControl = new FormControl();   
onChange(value) {
    this.propagateChange(value);  
 }   
writeValue(value: any) {
    this.InputValue = value;  
 } 
  registerOnChange(fn: any) 
{
    this.propagateChange = fn;  
 }   
registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.propagateTouched = fn;   
}  
 propagateChange = (_: any) => { }  
 propagateTouched = (_: any) => { } 
}
```

html file:

```
<input [(ngModel)]='InputValue' (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" />
<ng-container *ngIf="control.dirty && control.touched && control.errors">
  <div *ngIf="control.errors.required">Value is required</div>
  <div *ngIf="control.errors.minlength">
    Value should be longer Required min value is
    {{ control.errors.minlength.requiredLength }}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

```
get name() {
    return this.cardForm.get('name');
}
<app-input [control]="name" formControlName="name">
</app-input>
```

Comment: it's **unnecesary** create a custom formControl (implements ControlValue accessor) you can pass a FormControl as `@Input`